# Spring batch: get exitStatusDescription in afterJob

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am new to Spring batch.
I've configurated a new project with this job:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@Log4j2
public class BatchConfiguration {

    /* ... */

    @Bean
    public Job myJob(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory, Step stepInit, Step stepMain, Step stepReport) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("myJob").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).start(stepInit).on(ExitStatus.FAILED.getExitCode()).fail().from(stepInit).on("*").to(stepMain).next(stepReport).end().listener(new BatchListener()).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step stepInit(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("stepInit").tasklet(BatchInitialize.builder().build()).build();
    }

    /* ... */
```

}

In BatchInitialize tasklet I've defined an exit status with errorDesc:

```
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@Log4j2
public class BatchInitialize implements Tasklet {

    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
        /* ... */

        if(CONDITION) {
            contribution.setExitStatus(new ExitStatus(ExitStatus.FAILED.getExitCode(), "ERROR DESC"));
            return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
        }

        /* ... */
    }

}
```

How can I get the error description in a class that implements JobExecutionListener?

```
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@Log4j2
public class BatchListener implements JobExecutionListener {

    @Override
    public void beforeJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
        //
    }

    @Override
    public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
        // jobExecution.getExitStatus().getExitCode() -> FAILED
        // jobExecution.getExitStatus().getExitDescription() -> ""
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the exit status of the step to `FAILED` and returning `RepeatStatus.FINISHED` does not make sense to me. If the tasklet failed, I would set its exit status and throw an exception instead (another option is to use the exception's message and set it to `ERROR DESC`).

Now if you want to get the exception in the listener, you can do something like:

```
@Override
public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
    List<Throwable> allExceptions = jobExecution.getAllFailureExceptions();
    // get the exception and its message
}
```

If you want to get the exist status of a particular step, you can do something like:

```
@Override
public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
    List<StepExecution> stepExecutions = jobExecution.getStepExectuions();
    // iterate and get the step execution  you want then get its exit status
}
```

Comment: You are right, but if I throw new exception I still have to set the "chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().getJobExecution().setExitStatus" value to recover the error description in the afterJob method, right?

Comment: oh wait, I think I misunderstood your initial question.. You have set the exit status of the step to `ERROR DESC` but you are trying to get it from the job execution here `// jobExecution.getExitStatus().getExitDescription() -> ""`. Are you sure you want to get it from the job execution and not from the step execution? like: `jobExecution.getStepExecutions()`, then you iterate on step execution to find the one for `stepInit` and do `stepExecution.getExitStatus.getExitDescription()`? This should work. If this is what you are looking for, I will update the answer.

Comment: Sorry, I describe my problem to you: if particular conditions occur during the batch execution (in any step), I need to stop the execution, set the status to FAILED and set a description. Which is the best solution?